# How to use Subsonic MVC Template?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subsonic

I started downloading the MVC Template, and created a new project using this template. I Compiled the application, and everything went fine so far.
My question is, where could i find the new sonic.exe file that generates the MVC DAL?
Is that the old sonic.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as you're not using Express then the classes are created when you build your applicaion. Sometimes this doesn't work and you'll need to right click on the Models/Classes.tt and choose 'Run custom tool'. 
You should then have a Classes.cs file nested under the Classes.tt file and the DAL objects are defined in there.

Comment: Did you see Rob's screencast? He just pressed the button he had in his Visual Studio, to run the Sonic.exe tool with the arguments, just like we used to do in the earlier versions of subsonic. 
Another question, what is the ApplicationServices connection string? Is there anywhere where I could find a tutorial about using the new Subsonic 3.0?
and by the way, Thanks for the Run Custom tool tip :)

Comment: SubSonic 3 uses t4 templates not sonic.exe. The ApplicationServices connections string is there for the standard asp.net user stuff, I haven't seen a good tutorial yet I've just been working on trial and error.

Comment: Thanks @Adam for your help. I think I did what you said, and it's working fine. I just changed my connection string in the web.config, and did the 'Run Custom Tool' trick you told me.
Then I did what Rob said in his latest screencast (http://msbluelight-0.agappdom.net/e1/d/58326/20300058.a/63378201600/0.hwzLyH5RPvBkxBNjLAK3dHDV3Js/video.wmv) about adding Controllers and Views. But the funny thing is that its very buggy!
I ran the application, and opened the Edit Employees Page (Northwind DB) for instance, then I pressed Delete, and it said "Delete Successfull" but its still there in the DB!